# MYSQL - Checking a var exists then updating if it does

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, twitch

Hi im coding a twitch bot. I want to have it check if someone is in the database if they are it adds 20 to their points.

For example it will have an array of viewers:

`['kong','plays']`

kongs points = `100`
plays points = `123`

Comment: first make a table then ask

Comment: i have made a table

Comment: tell your table and column name

Comment: table = "points"
column = "points"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 update table1
      set ponits=ponits+20
      where name=someOneName;
```

i hope it works,
it is just a update query